# Opencart installation - curl and gd extension setup issue

Tags: php, curl, opencart2.x

OpenCart 2.2
Apache 2.4 - 64 bit version
PHP 7.0.4 - 64 bit version
Windows 7 - 64 bit version
MySQL 5.7
Chrome and IE
I don't use WAMP

I received an error message on CURL and GD extensions during my OpenCart installation. I uncommented the extension=php_curl.dll and extension=php_gd2.dll in the PHP.ini file and ensured they exists in the ext directory. After a restart of my Apache server, the issue with GD extension went away but the CURL extension issue persists. Restarted my laptop and the issue still persists. Can some assist?

Individually, my server, phpMyAdmin, MySQL works well.

Answer (score 0):

My issue is resolved:

One of the other thread gave me the solution. 
I added the PHP path to the Windows Path variable. Then restarted Apache.

In Control Panel -> System click on Advanced System Settings and use the button Environment Variables. Under System Variables you will find the Path variable. Edit it and append ;C:\OpenCart\PHP to it - or whatever the path to your PHP folder is.